# Is there a way to transfer a VS project to another computer and keep all the same files open?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I frequently take projects between work and home on a flash drive. I zip up the project with 7zip, take it to the new computer, delete the old project, and extract the newer version. But after doing this the solution doesn't open the files I had open previously like it normally does when re-opening a solution without replacing it with a new version.

The 7z file does include the hidden .vs folder which I believe is where the list of open files is supposed to be saved.

Comment: If I remember correctly, the base path needs to match exactly. So if they're stored on your desktop in `c:\users\JohnDoe\Projects\etc` and on your laptop in `c:\users\SilentSin\Project\etc` then it won't work. But if the files are in the exact same path it may.

Comment: That's ... lame. Might there be a way to get it to use relative paths instead?

Comment: learn git if you haven't

Comment: No way to do that. It's very old functionality dating back to 2003 era's.

Answer (score 0):

My [Task Canvas](https://vlasovstudio.com/task-canvas/) extension automatically saves open files on solution closing and restores them when you reopen the solution. It works with relative paths and information is saved to a .TaskCanvasSL file in the solution directory.

(But this is just one feature and doesn't justify purchase if you don't need the whole code fragments and tasks concept.)